# Data Structure Recommendation, Nuclides

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I'm writing a program to do various calculations involving nuclides. Some of these involve binding energies, magnetic moments, etc. Part of the program will need to be the storing of some dictionary, list, or something I'm unaware of as a novice Python programmer. I'd like to (by hand) create a set that contains Z, N, masses etc. Specifically, I'd like a structure that has multiple traits to a piece. I've thought of making a nested dictionary (maybe calling an attribute, `nuclides[C14[attribute]]`), but don't think this is intuitive. Here's the trickiest part, I'd like nuclides to referable by either Z and N, and by a string (e.g. nuclides['14C'] or nuclides[6,8]). As far as I know, dictionaries are only referenced by their label, so I'm not sure if dictionaries are ideal.

TL;DR
What's the best format for storing numerous of sets of integers/floats and a unique string where each set can be referenced by either it's string or pair of numbers.

An example of application, if say given 238Pu, finding the daughter nuclide and it's mass (both of which are in this table/data) from alpha decay.

Comment: Have a look at pandas dataframes. More info [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf).

Comment: @Xukrao, this is a wonderful diagram (plus documentation). I'm looking into it now. Thank you